# WSL2 || sed: can't read /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bug-reporting

I was opening VSCode via WSL, it was loading. I figured out I wouldn't use it, so I closed it, but the terminal closed with it, and I didn't gave it much attention. When I tried opening the terminal again, this is what I saw:

[image: Panic!]

And then, using `explorer.exe .` I got into the home folder, and my profile 'rodrigo' wasn't there.

I got terrified. I closed the terminal, tried opening up the Ubuntu 20.04 folder from the explorer. It was taking too long, so I stopped it and tried opening again the Ubuntu via Windows terminal and vòilá, it opened. I was relieved.

[image: relief.]

If it worked, why am I asking about it here? It worked while I was writing this question, so I'll post anyways, as there are only 2 other guys that posted about it, and didn't got a proper response or a solution. In case it happens again, I'm posting this question.

`sudo` didn't work and neither did `apt` or any other basic commands.

Comment: facing same issue rn. can't fix it : (

Comment: I got it fixed. I opened it with command `wsl` in cmd and it worked and then started working again in windows terminal also.

Comment: @Back2Lobby You may want to write an answer detailing how you got it fixed. It may help others.